# How to soft wrap text at column number lower than window width?

Tags: wrapping, textwidth

I developed [prompter.vim](https://github.com/solyarisoftware/prompter.vim), a vim plugin that autocomplete buffer text using LLMs completions.
The completion is a multi-line text insertion appended at the end to the buffer.

I would like to have completion text optionally justified in a fixed width of columns (say 80). This would be like `:set textwidth=80`, except with a soft wrap.

Well, [a workaround could be to reformat the inserted text entering `gqG`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3033455/1786393), but this solution inserts newlines and modifies the text.

Instead I would like a soft-wrap "non-invasive" solution that only modifies the visual appearance.

Comment: You could add a vertical buffer and make sure the initial buffer has a width of 80 columns?

Answer (score 2):

I have found that vim post-9.0 patches and nvim 0.10.0 have an inline virtual-text feature to realize this. I implemented a [plugin](https://github.com/rickhowe/wrapwidth). Hope to help you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no *simple* way to wrap at a specific column. You can soft-wrap at the edge of a window (`:set wrap`), or hard-wrap (*e.g.*, with `gq` as mentioned), or write some code to do something "funky" (like using a second window purely to control wrapping…).